# macos system Anaconda, Jupyter error:Server error: Traceback (most recent call last): ; NotADirectoryError: [Errno 20] Not a directory:

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, conda

guys plz help me out with this. I am beginner in programming and encounter this technical issue that I could not solve for a long time

I'm using a MacBook,a macOS system. After I install an anaconda following the instruction from the offical site and as I launch jupyter notebook from the anaconda portal the server error keeps showing up and find no director

```
Server error: Traceback (most recent call last): File "/Users/zhongyuanzhang/Desktop/Anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1699, in _execute result = await result File "/Users/zhongyuanzhang/Desktop/Anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 209, in wrapper yielded = next(result) File "/Users/zhongyuanzhang/Desktop/Anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/services/contents/handlers.py", line 112, in get path=path, type=type, format=format, content=content, File "/Users/zhongyuanzhang/Desktop/Anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/services/contents/filemanager.py", line 427, in get model = self._dir_model(path, content=content) File "/Users/zhongyuanzhang/Desktop/Anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/services/contents/filemanager.py", line 334, in _dir_model if self.allow_hidden or not is_file_hidden(os_path, stat_res=st): File "/Users/zhongyuanzhang/Desktop/Anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/utils.py", line 149, in is_file_hidden_posix stat_res = os.stat(abs_path) NotADirectoryError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/Users/zhongyuanzhang/bin'
```

screenshot of the problem[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OtJN.png)

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). In general, code/errors/data in text format >>>> code/errors/data as an image >> nothing. Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: _IOS system MacBook_ What do you mean? How exactly did you install Anaconda?

Comment: Restart your jupyter notebook

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I have restarted for many times but it just won't work

Answer (score 1):

So the error says directory `/users/zhongyuan/bin/` does not exists!